# increase height and width of file upload field

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a file upload field for upload which is inside a div which 150px x 150px and transparent(opacity:0;). i want a click on any part inside the div to pup up the file dialog box so the user can select his file to upload so i want to increase its height and width. no method of mine works. how do i solve this?

```
<div id="adds" align="center" style="cursor:pointer; cursor:hand;">
   <h1 style="margin-top:45px;">
      <span>Select<br />photo</span>
      <input type="file" name="upper" id="upper" width="150" height="150" />
   </h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have an extra closing div tag at the end of your example.

Comment: It can be done easily using javascript...! Do u want to use javascript?

Comment: Find out what you expect... http://www.ishtaventures.in/carrier.php

Comment: check this link http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="upper" name="upper" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" />
```

CSS

```
#upper {width: 150px; height: 150px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#adds input {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Use CSS. Please stop using inline styles, but just so you know, inline styles should use this syntax: `<input style="height:150px"; width:150px;"`

[Live demo here.](http://jsbin.com/ujuJOju/1/edit)

Comment: we can suggest inline style as external and embedded . solution is  not use width and height directly u can use style tag ............

Comment: LOL. Did you seriously downvote me then rip off my answer? Nice :)

Comment: i didn't down vote. if i am then it is a mistaken click sorry.

Comment: @kaydee I was referring to Rituraj. He updated his answer to use css like mine and then criticized me :) Anyway, inline styles are considered bad practice. CSS is for style, so use that! If you appreciate my answer, please accept (click the arrow).

Answer (score 0):

In HTML:

```
<form> <input type="file" /> </form>
```

In CSSs:

```
input[type='file']{width:150px;height:150px;}
```

Answer (score -1):

**in css**

```
#upper
{width:150px;
height:150px;
}
```

**in html**

```
<input type="file" name="upper" id="upper"  />
```

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of inline styles.